# After upgrading to Ubuntu 22.04, WiFi has stopped working completely. Even after installing the driver, it doesn't connect to any available network

Tags: drivers, wireless, upgrade, 22.04

I was using Ubuntu 20.04 LTS (which I had upgraded from 18.04 LTS). I upgraded to 22.04.1LTS. After the upgrade, the WiFi driver was missing (typical Ubuntu upgrade). In 20.04 I used to fix this issue using a GitHub repo **lwfinger/rtlwifi_new**, which is now missing.

So after a lot of searching and trying to find the correct solution, I implemented [this](https://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2021/01/install-rtl8188eu-rtl8723ds-drivers-ppa-ubuntu-20-04/).

Now, this allowed me to see the WiFi networks available, as opposed to showing WiFi adaptor not detected.

But my WiFi is not connecting to any network, encrypted or open, whatsoever.

It just keeps trying to connect, asks me for password 3-4 times and then stops.
And for the open network, it just keeps trying and stops after a while. Attached an image below.[image]

This is really frustrating. And I am unable to find any meaningful solution or rationale behind this bug.

A solution to this would be highly appreciated. Any explanation too would be appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

EDIT 1: RTL8723DE, in case it helps to solve.

Comment: I have tried all (2 drivers) the available drivers in Software & Updates. Neither of them solve this issue.

Comment: firewall enabled?

Comment: Is it a HP laptop?

Comment: @Jeremy31 yes, hp 15q-ds0009tu

Comment: It might be easiest to take the back cover off the laptop and change the antenna to the other connector on the wifi card if there is one.  HP was known to use only one antenna on the RTL8723BE and the RTL8723DE chipsets, later models may have only one antenna connector on the wifi chip

Comment: Just take it very slow removing the antenna from the chip

Answer (score -1):

Downgrading the kernel solved the issue for my RTL8821CE, write `sudo apt install linux-image-` and press tab a few times, a list of different kernel versions will show up, then find the one that suits you with trial and error, I hope this helps

note: older kernels do not have the support for the driver but the third party driver works correctly when combined with them

Comment: 3rd party driver as in? Can you pls point me to a link?

Comment: https://github.com/smlinux/rtl8723de
or
https://github.com/Ecos-hj/rtl8723de
may work

Comment: NOT applicable or useful/helpful for the actual chipset of the question. And there's no need to use older and likely already unsupported kernels for RTL8821ce.

Comment: @ChanganAuto this solved the issue for me and some other users on AU

Comment: No, installing the `rtl8821ce-dkms` package might have improved the experience when compared to the default driver and for installing it there was absolutely no need for older kernels. I have one working perfectly in 22.04 for all kernel versions with the aforementioned package. And all of this is totally irrelevant for the actual chipset in the question which has some problems of its own (read the comments by Jeremy31, an actual expert, to understand). What you posted here is a comment about a different chipset and, again, with wrong assumptions.